# Call php web service with url

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

Is there call php web service with url like asp.net web service?
in asp.net web service we can call method with url example :

```
www.example.com/webservice.asmx?method=hello&name=world
```

Comment: Sure. You'd have to write PHP code to do stuff, but stuff like `www.example.com/webservice.php?method=hello&name=world` works just fine once you code it.

Comment: I am assuming you know what apache2 is.....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like that :

```
<?php
function hello($arg) {
        echo "hello method : $arg";
}

function hello2($arg) {
        echo "hello2 method : $arg";
}

$method = $_GET['method'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

call_user_func($method, $name);
?>
```